# How to properly display image in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I found this code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

img = Image.open(r"Sample.jpg")
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()
tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
canvas.create_image(250, 250, image=tk_img)

root.mainloop()
```

It displays any picture in 500x500px resolution. I tried to change it and display it in its original size:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

img = Image.open(r"D:/1.jpg")
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=img.width, height=img.height)
canvas.pack()
tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
canvas.create_image(img.width/2, img.height/2, image=tk_img)

root.mainloop()
```

But something went wrong and the picture with a size of 604x604px shows in a window with a size of 602x602px, but the window size is correct.
[Take a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0YCx.png) [(full image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2NJj.jpg).
What am I doing wrong?

P.S. Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, no, your first example still cuts off by a few pixels. All top level windows will have padding around their absolute borders to prevent other elements from 'bleeding' into the borders and looking unprofessional.

You are still being given a canvas of 604 pixels by 604 pixels, but the root window itself is asserting its padding. I could not find any way of removing this top level padding, and it may very well appear differently in other operating systems. A work-around could be to request a canvas size that is slightly larger than the image you would like to display.

Another issue, if you're aiming for precision, would be the line...

```
canvas.create_image(img.width/2, img.height/2, image=tk_img)
```

Which could create off-by-one errors if your width or height is an odd number. You can anchor images to the north-west corner and place them at the co-ordinates `(0, 0)` like such:

```
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tk.NW, image=tk_img)
```

Comment: The screen shot linked in the question shows that window borders are not included in the size, there's an additional blank space between the window border and the image.